# Finding the row that contains two cell values in two different columns

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a pair of If statements to check two columns for the value from two cells (e.g. check Column A for B3.Value, and check Column G for B2.Value), only to realize that this would not return a result based on those values existing in the same row, but only if they existed at all in the table.

My goal is to have the code check to see if a row exists with B3.Value in Column A *and* B2.Value in Column G. These columns are located in the DataBodyRange of a table (because the range will be dynamic). Right now, the incorrect code that I've got is

```
Dim tblData As ListObject
Dim checkDate As Date
Dim reportSup As Range
Dim reportDate As Range

Set tblData = Worksheets("Data").ListObjects(1)
Set reportSup = Worksheets("Daily").Range("B2")
Set reportDate = Worksheets("Daily").Range("B3")

  checkDate = WorksheetFunction.Max(Worksheets("Data") _
    .ListObjects("Data") _
    .ListColumns("Date") _
    .DataBodyRange)

  If reportDate.Value = checkDate Then

    If Not IsError(Application.Match(reportSup.Value, _
      tblData.ListColumns(7).DataBodyRange, 0)) Then

      MsgBox "You have already reported for this period. " & _
        "Please enter a different date."
      reportDate.Select
      Exit Sub

    End If

  End If
```

I'm not sure if I should be using EVALUATE or INDEX to get it to find the row that meets both criteria so that if that row exists, pop the MsgBox, otherwise continue on with the rest of the code.

Comment: I am confused by the "My goal is to have the code check to see if a row exists with B3.Value in Column A and B2.Value in Column G. These columns are located in the DataBodyRange of a table (because the range will be dynamic)."      Can you help me understand your goal again. Perhaps show an example in spreadsheet form?

Comment: Does `Worksheets(Sheet1).Range("B3").Value` exist in `Worksheets(Sheet2).ListObjects(1).ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange` AND **in that same row** does ``Worksheets(Sheet1).Range("B2").Value` exist in `Worksheets(Sheet2).ListObjects(1).ListColumns(7).DataBodyRange` TRUE/FALSE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly, this does what you want. It uses Find to find the B3 value in column A and then checks the corresponding column G value. I've assumed this can only happen once, so code will need amending if this is not the case.

```
Sub x()

Dim tblData As ListObject
Dim reportSup As Range
Dim reportDate As Range, rFind As Range, s As String

Set tblData = Worksheets("Data").ListObjects(1)
Set reportSup = Worksheets("Daily").Range("B2")
Set reportDate = Worksheets("Daily").Range("B3")

With tblData.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange
    Set rFind = .Find(What:=reportDate, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
        s = rFind.Address
        Do
            If rFind.Offset(, 6).Value = reportSup.Value Then
                MsgBox "Both values found in row " & rFind.Row
                Exit Sub
            Else
                Set rFind = .FindNext(rFind)
            End If
         Loop While rFind.Address <> s
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Both Column A and Column G have repeating values (e.g. a date can appear multiple times in Column A, and string can appear multiple times in Column G), however the combination of the two should be unique. (e.g. There may be multiple rows with yesterday's date in Column A, but only one of those rows can contain the string "Person 1" in Column G.)

I'll test this and get back to you!